# SQL subqueries"Every derived table must have its own alias" error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this query with multiple subqueries and I got an error message "Every derived table must have its own alias".

```
SELECT SUM(set1 + set2 + set3)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(b.`Set1-p1`) as set1 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set1-p1` > b.`Set1-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 + (
    
SELECT COUNT(b.`Set2-p1`) as set2 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set2-p1` > b.`Set2-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 + (

SELECT COUNT(b.`Set3-p1`) as set3 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set3-p1` > b.`Set3-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 ) 
    )
)
```

I tried to name the tables at the end but then I got this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `T1`) AS `T2`
) AS `T3`
) AS `T4` LIMIT 0, 50' at line 16"

```
SELECT SUM(set1 + set2 + set3)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(b.`Set1-p1`) as set1 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set1-p1` > b.`Set1-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 + (
    
SELECT COUNT(b.`Set2-p1`) as set2 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set2-p1` > b.`Set2-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 + (

SELECT COUNT(b.`Set3-p1`) as set3 FROM synbadminton as b
INNER JOIN syngame as g 
ON b.GameID = g.GameID
WHERE b.`Set3-p1` > b.`Set3-p2` && g.PlayerOneID = 12 AS `T1`) AS `T2`
) AS `T3`
) AS `T4`
```

Comment: As far as I can see it is only the final parenthesis that needs to be followed by an alias. The other two, while they are subqueries, they are used as expressions returning one value each, they shouldn't require aliases.

Comment: @tinazmu which means? how should I do it?

Comment: I have noticed that the whole query is wrong: do you want to run three queries, each returning a single numeric result, and then add them up? also, what is your database? I  don't know which database supports && operator.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Always add a dbms tag to your SQL question - extra important when product specific syntax is used. (As it is now you have accepted an answer only running on an - for the rest of us - unknown dbms.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run three queries, each returning a single numeric result, and then add them up, yielding a single number:

```
SELECT 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(b.`Set1-p1`) as set1 
    FROM synbadminton as b
    INNER JOIN syngame as g 
    ON b.GameID = g.GameID
    WHERE b.`Set1-p1` > b.`Set1-p2` 
          AND g.PlayerOneID = 12
    )
    + (
    SELECT COUNT(b.`Set2-p1`) as set2 
    FROM synbadminton as b
    INNER JOIN syngame as g 
    ON b.GameID = g.GameID
    WHERE b.`Set2-p1` > b.`Set2-p2` 
          AND g.PlayerOneID = 12
    )
    + (
    SELECT COUNT(b.`Set3-p1`) as set3 
    FROM synbadminton as b
    INNER JOIN syngame as g 
    ON b.GameID = g.GameID
    WHERE b.`Set3-p1` > b.`Set3-p2` 
          AND g.PlayerOneID = 12 
    )
```